# Creating [][] operator for class in c++

Tags: c++, operator-overloading

I am making a Pentago game for someone, and I wanted to write a good code, so I decided to use operator overloading.

We have 2 classes; first one is Block class (which represents every single block of the board) and the second one is Set class (which represents a 3*3 table of blocks). 
Now I want to use Set as a 2d array so I can use set[foo][foo].
Can you help me to make an operator like this?

Comment: Perhaps operator overloading is not a good choice for this. Just write a method instead

Comment: If the memory is contiguous, just return a pointer to the address of the first element of that row from `operator []` and it should work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no `operator[][]`. If you want to provide those semantics you need to overload `operator[]` such that it returns another object that also overloads `operator[]`.

Your case can be solved using a *vector of vectors*:

```
#include <vector>
#include <cstdint>
#include <iostream>

struct Block
{
    int value = 0;
};

class Set
{
    std::vector<std::vector<Block> > grid;

public:
    Set(): grid(3, std::vector<Block>(3)) {} // 3 x 3

    std::vector<Block>& operator[](std::size_t x) { return grid[x]; }
};

int main()
{
    using std::size_t;

    Set set;

    set[1][1].value = 1;

    for(size_t x = 0; x < 3; ++x)
    {
        for(size_t y = 0; y < 3; ++y)
        {
            std::cout << set[x][y].value << ' ';
        }
        std::cout << '\n';
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
0 0 0 
0 1 0 
0 0 0
```

This works because `Set::operator[]` returns reference to a `std::vector` and the `std::vector` overloads `operator[]` to return a reference to a `Block`.

Comment: Using a default class that has the [] operator overloaded sounds good. I will use this. thanks!

Answer (score 3):

There are (at least) two ways to go here.

---

The first is to make something like a `set_row` class, which is a proxy. So you'd have something like

```
class set
{
public:
    set_row operator[](size_t row)
    {
        // Return a proxy object that just sees the correct row.
        return set_row(internal_buffer_pointer[row]);
    }

    ...
};
```

where `set_row` is something like

```
class set_row
{
public:
     // Ctor takes a row

     // Take a column, and return a reference to the correct column in the row.
     element &operator[](size_t column);
};
```

From experience (on, ahem, VisualC++), this was **slow**, as it will need to construct a proxy object for each access.

---

The second is to forgo `operator[]`, and use `operator()`:

```
class set
{
public:
    element &operator()(size_t row, size_t col);


    ...
};
```

It would be nice using `operator[]`, but, unfortunately, you can't do that with it.

Comment: You should not return a reference to a temporary in `set_row &set::operator[]`.

Comment: @rodrigo Many thanks - you are absolutely correct. Fixed.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. The second solution looks better and more straightforward!

Comment: @AmiTavory: are you sure that returning a reference to a row-access object is slow? With what compiler? Compiling with `-O3` on both `g++` and `clang++` the generated code is quite efficient (the temporary row-access object indeed is not created at all).

Comment: @6502 I'm ashamed to say that it was with Visual C++. Thankfully, it's been years since I've been doing Windows stuff, but it did slow down production code by much. Thanks for the pertinent comment regarding those compilers!

Answer (score 3):

A very simple solution is

```
struct MyClass {
    int x[3][3];
    int* operator[](int row) { return &(x[row][0]); }
};
```

i.e. returning an `element*` from `operator[]`.

This allows using

```
myinstance[row][col]
```

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to supply an `operator[][]` for a class.

However, if your `Set` supplies an `operator[]()`, that operator can return a reference to something else that also has an `operator[]()`.

For example;

```
 class Row
 {
      public:

           Block &operator[](int block_no) {return data[block_no];};

      private:

           std::vector<Block> data;
 };

 class Set
 {
       public:

          Row &operator[](int row_no) {return row[row_no];};

       private:
           std::vector<Row> row;
 };

 int main()
 {
     Set s;
       // assume s is set up appropriately
     Block b = s[2][3];    //  equivalent to s.operator[](2).operator[](3)
 }
```

Obviously, it is also necessary to do relevant error checking, set up the contents of the classes correctly, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the memory is contiguous, you can return a pointer to the first element of the row.

**[Working example](http://ideone.com/AKyRWH)**

```
#include <iostream>

class MyType
{
public:
    static const size_t rows = 3;
    static const size_t columns = 3;
    static const size_t size = rows * columns;

    MyType()
    {
        for(size_t index = 0; index < 9; ++index)
        {
            data[index] = index;
        }
    }

    int* operator[](size_t index)
    {
        return &data[rows * index];
    }

private:
    int data[size];
};

int main()
{
    MyType instance;

    std::cout << instance[2][1] << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: That's true. However, note that you forgo the ability to do stuff like check for illegal indexes in debug mode. Personally, I would not do that.

Comment: @AmiTavory thanks for the input, I suppose it could be done with iterators instead. This is just the simplest way I could think of.